# Filter CSV to show only rows with 'games'

Tags: javascript

It has been trial and mostly error... I have javascript to parse all rows of a csv file but I want to limit it to only those rows that have a specific string ... games .  Any ideas on how I can edit this code to make that happen?  Thank you.

```
$('#left').ready(function() {

promise = $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    dataType:"text",
    url:"games.csv",
    cache:false
});

promise.done(function(data){

    var dataArr = data.split("\n");

    $.each(dataArr,function(){
        if (this != "") {

            var row = new String("");
            valArr = this.split(",");
                row += "<tr>"

            $.each(valArr, function(){
                row += "<td>" + this +"</td>"
            });     

                row += "</tr>"

             $('#games tbody').append(row);

        }

    });

});

// Run script if request fails
promise.fail(function() {
   console.log('A failure ocurred');
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this.

See if it works.

```
promise.done(function (data) {
  var i, nodes, rows, cols, html;

  nodes = [];
  rows = data.split("\n");
  for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
  {
    if (rows[i] === "")
    {
      continue; // empty line
    }

    if (rows[i].indexOf("games") === -1)
    {
      continue; // does not contain "games"
    }

    cols = rows[i].split(",");
    html = "<tr><td>" + cols.join("</td><td>") + "</td></tr>";
    nodes.push($(html));
  }

  $("#games tbody").empty();
  while (nodes.length > 0)
  {
    $("#games tbody").append(nodes.shift());
  }
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd build an array of objects before building the dom.

1. Parse your CSV file and build objects based on the keys row, assuming you are using a keys row (e.g. top row of most CSV exported data).
2. Store those objects in an array
3. Filter the array using `var filtered = array.filter( callbackFunc )`
4. Then build your DOM rows based on the `filtered` array